# Eigenspace and Eigenvalues (Comprehension Question)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> I'm a bit confused on a couple linear algebra topics..
>
> Say I have a $5 \times  5$ matrix, with 3 eigenvalues     With One of
>   the corresponding eigen-spaces being 1 dimensional Another
>   corresponding eigen-spaces dimension being 2 dimensional
>
> Would it be possible for that matrix to **NOT** be diagonalizeable?

I would say **YES** because if the $3rd$ eigenvalue
and it's associated eigen-space dimension is not $2$
then it can't possibly be diagonalizeable.

Is this logical? Also would it be possible to have an eigen-space
with dimension $0$?

Also if anyone could help me understand how this relates to the geometric multiplicities and algebraic multiplicities it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Algebraic multiplicity is the number of times the eigenvalue is a root of the characteristic polynomial. Geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace. Furthermore, your matrix is diagonalizable iff for all eigenvalues the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are equal. Therefore, in your given example, the matrix would not be diagonalizable if the third eiegnvalue has geometric multiplicity of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. To answer your other question, yes the third eigenvalue must have eigenspace with dimension $1$, since it does not make sense to have an eigenspace of dimension $0$.

More concretely, you are given that the geometric multiplicities (dimension of eigenspace) of the first two eigenvalues are $1$ and $2$ respectively. 
Since you are in a $5$-dimensional space, the geometric multiplicity of the third eigenvalue must be $1$ or $2$ (since the sum of the geometric multiplicities is $\le 5$).

- If it is $2$, then the sum of the geometric multiplicities is $5$, so the matrix would be diagonalizable, a contradiction.
- Thus the geometric multiplicity of the third eigenvalue must be $1$, as you reasoned.

On the other hand, the algebraic multiplicities will always add up to $5$ and each must be at least their geometric multiplicity. So the three eigenvalues' algebraic multiplicities must be $(1,2,2)$ or $(2,2,1)$ or $(1,3,1)$.

---

You can explicitly construct examples using a Jordan matrix. For example, the following matrix has algebraic multiplicities $1,2,2$.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\
& \lambda_2 \\
&& \lambda_2 \\
&&& \lambda_3 & 0\\
&&&1&\lambda_3
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Why not (2,1,2)?

Comment: The geometric multiplicity of the second eigenvalue is $2$, so the algebraic multiplicity must be at least $2$.